# Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found

Tags: theme-development

What would cause this error:

Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /home/test/dummyurl.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/upload-zip.php on line 14

PHP Version is 5.3.1

Does WP have a built in function I should use instead? Like perhaps the "unzip_file" function line 525 of ./wp-admin/includes/file.php"?

```
function openZip($file_to_open) { 
    global $target;  
    $zip = new ZipArchive();  //This is line 14
    $x = $zip->open($file_to_open);  
    if($x === true) {  
        $zip->extractTo($target);  
        $zip->close();                
        unlink($file_to_open);  
    } else {  
        die("There was a problem. Please try again!");  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means your PHP installation doesn't have [the Zip library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php). You can [install it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php) by recompiling PHP with the `--enable-zip` option, or install [the PECL package](http://pecl.php.net/package/zip).

Comment: if you are on shared hosting I would recommend writing to your host to see if they can enable it for your site. They may have it disabled as zipping can be a CPU intensive operation.

Comment: Interesting. How do the wordpress installer routines get around this? I would want to do similar.

Comment: @Scott B: There is a function [`unzip_file()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L512) which first tries `ZipArchive` like you do, but if it does not exist it falls back on [PclZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/), an zip library written in PHP. So I suggest you try to use this function `unzip_file()` too, as it will probably always exist in WordPress. (Maybe we should rewrite this question so it becomes "How to unzip files without `ZipArchive`?")

Comment: I agree, I've added it as a separate question > http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8213/how-to-unzip-files-without-ziparchive